# Using Google PageSpeed API in Python: Batch request returning None

Tags: python, google-api, pagespeed

I'm attempting to make a batch request to Google's PageSpeed API, but I'm only getting None back. When I make the requests separately, they succeed and return the expected information.

The excerpted code below is currently running in a Jupyter notebook on Azure.

```
!pip install -U google-api-python-client

from apiclient.http import BatchHttpRequest
from apiclient.discovery import build

google_api_key = "mykey"
ps_service = build('pagespeedonline', 'v4', developerKey = google_api_key)

list_of_urls = [my list]

def list_websites(request_id, response, exception):
    if exception is not None:
        print(response)
    else:
        print("This is an exception: " + str(exception) + "\n" + request_id)

ps_batch = ps_service.new_batch_http_request(callback = list_websites)

service_list = []

for k, v in list_of_urls.items():
    addr = list_of_urls[k]["website"]
    service_list.append(ps_service.pagespeedapi().runpagespeed(url = addr))

for req in service_list:
    ps_batch.add(req)

ps_batch.execute()
```

Running this returns a list of strings where the responses (and the exceptions) print as None. My Python is rusty and I expect I'm missing something basic, but really appreciate any advice.

Result example:

```
This is an exception: None
None
This is an exception: None
None
This is an exception: None
None
```

Answer (score 0):

My code has a dumb error: It attempts to print the response in the exception block, and the exception in the response block.

Instead:

```
def list_websites(request_id, response, exception):
    if exception is not None:
        print("This is an exception: " + str(exception) + " " + request_id)
    else:
        print(response)
```